# Testing modules in octave

Tags: python, testing, octave

In my python programming, I use the "If **name** == **main**:" test to include test cases in my individual modules. Here is a typical set up:

```
def addition (a, b):
    return a+b

if __name__ == '__main__':

    x = 4
    y = 6

    print addition(x,y)
```

Where 'addition' is my function. If function is called from another module, passing some inputs a and b, addition will return the sum. Additionally, I can run this script directly (suppose it is saved as addition.py), in which case the if clause will return True and proceed to the print statement, which is a trivial test case.

For more detailed explanation of the "if name == main" construction, see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

My question:

Is there a way to mimic this structure in Octave programming language? I  would like to know if there is a similar way to write test cases into my Octave scripts, such that the test case will run if I run the script directly but will not run if the script is called by another program.

Comment: Is `'__name__'` a typo?. It should be `__name__`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Octave has test and demos blocks which are documented on its [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Test-and-Demo-Functions.html). However, I'd still point you to its source for examples (since Octave uses them internally), rather than the manual. Look at the bottom of the function files for [strjoin](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/cb377af34c00/scripts/strings/strjoin.m) and [rot90](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/cb377af34c00/scripts/general/rot90.m) for their tests.

Your specific example could become (I used 2 different types of test for sake of example):

```
function c = addition (a, b)
  c = a+b;
endfunction

%!assert (addition (4, 6), 10)

%!test
%! a = 4;
%! b = -4;
%! c = addition (a, b);
%! assert (c, 0)
```

This could be easily tested from the Octave prompt with `test addition`.